# Can I determine if the SolarWinds TFTP server dated April 2019 is compromised?

Tags: security, tftp

SolarWinds has been [in the news](https://www.wired.com/story/russia-solarwinds-hack-roundup/) due to the hack of their servers.
It is unclear how far back the compromise goes.
The only product I have used from them is their [free TFTP server](https://www.solarwinds.com/free-tools/free-tftp-server).
Has the "fingerprint" of the compromise been documented to allow determination if a specific download is affected? Are the compromised files now detectable with commercial virus/malware scanners?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SolarWinds cyberattack was a supply chain attack. The nation-state threat actor(s) gained access to the SolarWinds Orion build system and added a backdoor to a legitimate Orion DLL, namely `SolarWinds.Orion.Core.BusinessLayer.dll`. This DLL was then distributed to SolarWinds customers via their automatic update platform used to push out new software updates. This DLL is loaded by `SolarWinds.BusinessLayerHost.exe`. The free SolarWinds TFTP Server does not use this update mechanism.

To date, the free TFTP server is not listed by SolarWinds as compromised. See https://www.solarwinds.com/securityadvisory for detailed information.

IOCs can be found at https://github.com/sophos-cybersecurity/solarwinds-threathunt and elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks - although the TFTP server is not included in the "NOT KNOWN TO BE AFFECTED" listing in the advisory, there is a note at the bottom that says "We have also found no evidence that any of our free tools... are impacted"